# Make Pointer Getter use unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

```
sf::RectangleShape* operator()()
{
    return &player;

} // RectangleShape Getter
```

Do I need to free memory after this getter? If yes, how would one do this with `unique_ptr`?

I tried

```
std::unique_ptr<sf::RectangleShape> operator()()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<sf::RectangleShape>(player);

} // RectangleShape Getter
```

But it says there is no matching function for the parenthesis operator. How else should this be done?

Comment: A unique pointer must either be returned from `make_unique` or otherwise be constructed from the value of a `new` expression.

Comment: What is `player`?

Comment: `player` doesn't seem to be a pointer, since you take its address in the first example

Comment: @Galik It is an `sf::RectangleShape`, nothing fancy. Think of it like a simple Class.

Comment: No. I'm just pointing out that if the first compiles then the second one is very unlikely to be correct.

Comment: @KerrekSB So i tried `return std::make_unique(&player);` and it gave me the error ` error: no matching function for call to 'make_unique(sf::RectangleShape*)'
   return std::make_unique(&player);`. Using & or * also didn't work

Comment: So do I have to manage memory myself in the first one? If not then I can just ignore the second one as I like the first syntax much better

Comment: Or is that only if I actually make a Pointer variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sf::RectangleShape* operator()()
{
    return &player;

} // RectangleShape Getter
```

> Do I need to free memory after this getter?

All you do is return a pointer to `player`. Assuming that is a member variable of the struct/class the above member function is a part of, then its lifetime is bound to the lifetime of the object you call that function with.

In particular that means that this is a bad idea:

```
struct Foo {
  sf::RectangleShape player;
  // ...
  // insert your operator here
};

sf::RectangleShape * some_function(void) {
  Foo f;
  return f(); // UB, returning pointer to object with automatic memory whose lifetime has ended
}
```

> [..] how would one do this with unique_ptr?

Assuming `sf::RectangleShape` has a copy constructor, then you could make a copy of `player`:

```
std::unique_ptr<sf::RectangleShape> operator()() {
  return make_unique<sf::RectangleShape>(player);
}
```

The copy you get that way is "yours", i.e. you can manage is lifetime as you want.

Comment: So if I use `make_unique` does it make a copy or is it the same object with the same properties?

Comment: It's a copy. Of course assuming objects of this type actually *can* be copied.

Comment: Okay, so that method is not viable as it has to be the same object. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `player` is member of a class and you are trying to hand out a pointer to it for it to modified outside the class?

In this case, the class it belongs to owns the memory and it is down to that class to handle freeing the data when it is destroyed. A pointer to that member should absolutely not be freed from outside the class.

It would help to have more information about the owning class, but if I can assume that `player` is a data member, then your first example is technically fine. However it is often more idiomatic to return a reference than pointer.

```
class SomeClass
{
    sf::RectangleShape player;
    sf::RectangleShape& operator()()
    {
        return player;
    }
};
```

If the above assumption is incorrect, you should show your full class definition so we have more information to form a correct solution.

Comment: Your assumption is correct and the only reason I use a pointer over a reference is, that it is more clear outside the class that it is not a copy, but indeed the member variable and that it should be handled carefully. As far as I found out now, you only have to care about memory management when making a pointer variable or using the `new` keyword. Is that correct?

Comment: You should worry about freeing memory whenever there is dynamic memory allocation e.g. using `new` or any of the C-style `alloc` variants. These are traditionally used if a resource is created inside and returned from a function, or the object is too big to allocate directly on the stack.

In these cases, it is often better to create a `unique_ptr` (via the `make_unique` function), as the resource is then cleaned up automatically when ptr goes out of scope.

You can use the `ptr.get()` function to get a raw pointer that can be passed 

... cont below ...

Comment: around so others can modify the resource. But they shouldn't attempt to free it.

Pointers don't inherently mean dynamic memory allocation - you can create a pointer to stack variable, for example. So you really need to think about who **owns** the object and where it is allocated.

This is why the smart pointers are recommended over raw pointers, because you implicitly give the resource a lifetime based on ownership, and therefore do not need to worry about freeing the memory.

You still need to be careful of dangling raw pointers to `unique_ptr` data after it is freed though.

Comment: Yeah, at the time I completely misunderstood pointers and the free store